# cucumber rake error in jenkins integration

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I am seeing

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- cucumber'
```

error in jenkins while trying to integrate cucumber ruby test to jenkins.

### The Rakefile has following code

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

task default: :cucumber

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = %w{--format pretty}
end
```

I think I need to use `bundle install` in the Rakefile but I don't know how to achieve this. Any pointers on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can run bundle install using backticks. Just make sure to run it before you need all your gems.

```
`bundle install`
```

Comment: using the jenkins 'use shell script' i got to the point where all the gems are installed but even after that the error lies.

`rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- cucumber
/Users/kshitij/office/actio-test-frame/Rakefile:1:in`` `<top (required)>'```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `rake` to run cucumber. Try running cucumber directly in your jenkins shell script. Once you've got that working then you can start using rake if you really want to.

Comment: Please could you answer this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612140/ruby-cucumber-integration-to-jenkins-bitbucket