# Ruby/Cucumber: Integration to Jenkins : Bitbucket

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, appium, rakefile

**NOTE: Jenkins linked to the machine, where all the automation set up is done, and cucumber test steps can be run with the command `cucumber` flawlessly.**

I have a repository in bitbucket, and I am trying to get it run on the jenkins on each change to my repository.

Currently, the tests that I have written with cucumber/gherkin and ruby are for mobile automation tests with appium using `appium_lib`

I am trying to get this run in the jenkins but, jenkins would keep displaying the error `can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a)` .

I am new to JENKINS integration.

1. I have integrated to bitbucket successfully
2. I have set up jenkins and configured the slave to be my machine* (where i have all the cucumber, appium and ruby set up done) and the slave shows as IDLE status.

I wanted to know if there are any additional steps that I have to install or configure in jenkins to have these tests running. I see that a workspace has been created by jenkins in the system and all the files has been copied to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**The error logs**

```
[Testappium] $ rake --rakefile /usr/local/bin/bundle
rake aborted!
can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a)
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
[CucumberReportPublisher] Compiling Cucumber Reports ...
[CucumberReportPublisher] Copying all json files from slave: /Users/jain/Documents/fslearning-android/workspace/Testappium to master reports directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Testappium/builds/13
[CucumberReportPublisher] Found 0 json files:
```

Comment: i think you're saying you can get on the box in question and run the command (that's failing in jenkins) successfully. if so, maybe you are using a different ruby (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273986/jenkins-slave-doesnt-use-same-ruby-version-as-on-local-terminal). try `which ruby` in both contexts. are you using rbenv or rvm (or similar) when you run it outside of jenkins? if so, you'll need to initialize these in order to use them from jenkins.

Comment: Ruby that is installed in my mac is 2.4.1., I am not using rvm or rbenv.

Comment: I had basically forgot to add `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`. I did a `bundle install` and it fixed all the errors